# android: usbManager.getDeviceList() returns empty list after boot

Tags: android, android-usb

I am developing an application, which uses a usb device through Usb host mode.
I use an IntentFilter for *ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED*, so I can connect and communicate with the device **after it is attached**.
The problem occurs when I turn in (or reboot) the phone with the usb device already **plugged in**. When I open my application after turning on, I cannot see the device.

The following code results in an empty deviceList.

```
usbManager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = usbManager.getDeviceList();
```

The Android Developers Reference says about the getDeviceList():

> The result will be empty if no devices are attached, or if USB host mode is  inactive or unsupported.

USB host mode is obviously supported on the phone, and a device is attached too. So I guess the host mode is inactive by default.

If I disconnect and reattach the usb device, it works perfectly, but because the device and the phone is in a custom-made holder together, reconnecting them is a bit complicated. Is there a way to activate the host mode from code?

Comment: I have a somewhat similar but opposite question, my ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED broadcast sends itself after a reboot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814702/prevent-usb-device-attached-launching-app-after-a-reboot